# What is HTTP header stands for 'x-auto-login'

Tags: http, http-headers

When i login with gmail , i see this header ('x-auto-login') in one of the http repsonse, what is the purpose of it:

```
gtglobal-ocsp.geotrust.com 
:Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 22:26:41 GMT
Expires: Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: GSE
Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:8823f898f8dsf8sd6g;Path=/;Expires=Sat, 05-Mar-2016 22:26:41 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly
GALX=axHR8TU45uo;Path=/;Secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10893354; includeSubDomains
x-auto-login: realm=com.google&args=service%3Dmail%26continue%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
```

[Note: I have intentionally changed the cookie value for security reason]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP header x-auto-login allows to auto-login a user in Chrome.
See here for a code reference.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/components/auto_login_parser/auto_login_parser.cc&q=x-auto-login&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=42

So if you use Chrome or Chromium at a site the has the header then Chrome will redirect to Google's openid consent page. If you are loggedin at Google already the login to the new site is quite smooth.

There does not seem to be an official description of the header nor a W3C standard for it.